# Odata Functions with Parameters throw 500

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2

i have a little Problem with one of my Controllers.

Everytime i try to call some function with parameter a 500 is thrown and while debugging i can see that the function is not even called.

First my WebApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<Entity>("Entities");
            builder.EntitySet<DataTypes>("DataTypes");
            builder.EntitySet<ObjectValue>("ObjectValues");
            builder.EntitySet<Attributes>("Attributes");
            builder.EntitySet<Objects>("Objects");
            builder.Namespace = "EAVService.Controllers";
            builder.Action("FullAttributes").Returns<IHttpActionResult>()
                .CollectionParameter<Attributes>("Attributes");
            builder.Action("FullValues").Returns<IHttpActionResult>()
                .CollectionParameter<ObjectValue>("ObjectValue");

            config.MapODataServiceRoute(
                routeName: "ODataRoute",
                routePrefix: "odata",
                model: builder.GetEdmModel());
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
        }
    }
```

My Entity:

```
[Table("ObjectValue")]
public partial class ObjectValue
{
    public ObjectValue()
    {


    }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ObjectId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Attribute { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256)]
    public string AttributeVal { get; set; }

    public virtual Attributes Attributes { get; set; }

    public virtual Objects Objects { get; set; }
}
```

and my Controller:

```
public class ObjectValuesController : ODataController
{
    private EAVModel db;

    public ObjectValuesController(IDbConnectionProvider provider)
    {
        db = new EAVModel(provider.GetDbConnection());
    }

    // GET: odata/ObjectValues
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<ObjectValue> GetObjectValues()
    {
        IQueryable<ObjectValue> query = db.ObjectValue.AsQueryable();
        return query;
    }

    // GET: odata/ObjectValues(5)
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<ObjectValue> GetObjectValues([FromODataUri] string key)
    {
        IQueryable<ObjectValue> result = db.ObjectValue.Where(objectValue => objectValue.ObjectId == Convert.ToInt32(key)).AsQueryable();

        return result;
    }
```

.... }

The first Get Method is working fine.

When it comes to the second Get with a Parameter i get an Internal Server Error.

http://localhost:80/EAVServiceAPI/odata/ObjectValues(1)

Someone who can give me a hint what could be wrong?

Regards
Andre

Answer (score 0):

The method with the key should return `ObjectValue` not `IQueryable<ObjectValue>` and the `key` parameter is wrong, it doesn't match the key on the `ObjectValue` object. Do you mean to have Key attributes on `ObjectId` and `Attribute` on `ObjectValue`? If so you need to have 2 key parameters on your `GetObjectValues` method with names that match the keys, otherwise remove one of the `Key` attributes and ensure the type of your `key` parameter matches the type of the key on `ObjectValue`.

Comment: Ok.. so i changed my method to: public ObjectValue GetObjectValues([FromODataUri] int ObjectId, string Attribute) {...} when i try to call the function with: link I now get the Error:

{
  "error":{
    "code":"","message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/EAVServiceAPI/odata/ObjectValues(ObjectId=1,Attribute='asda')'.","innererror":{
      "message":"No routing convention was found to select an action for the OData path with template '~/entityset/key'.","type":"","stacktrace":""
    }
  }
}

 Regards Andre

Comment: Do you really want 2 keys? `ObjectId` sounds like the key to me.

Comment: Yes i want to key. ObjectId and Attribute are Foreignkeys from different tables.

Regards
Andre

Comment: OK, maybe try adding `[FromODataUri]` to the `Attribute` parameter as well?

Comment: Right.. should by there.. missed it :)
public ObjectValue GetObjectValues([FromODataUri] int ObjectId, [FromODataUri] string Attribute)

But still the same error

Comment: Try changing the name of the method with the keys to be `GetObjectValue`

Comment: Hi tom
Thalt also doesnt work for me

Method:
 public ObjectValue GetObjectValue([FromODataUri] int ObjectId, [FromODataUri] string Attribute)
        {...}

Call:
http://localhost/EAVServiceAPI/odata/ObjectValue(ObjectId=1,Attribute='Description')

Comment: This blog post should talk you through the problem: http://chris.eldredge.io/blog/2014/04/24/Composite-Keys/

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what exactly i did wrong in my configuration but this solved my issue:

http://localhost/EAVServiceAPI/odata/ObjectValues?objectId=1

Regards
Andre